# Matlab - Concatenating non-scalar nested structures with empty fields without losing proper indexing

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, is there a way to concatenate a non-scalar structure without losing the empty fields?  This is interfering with my ability to index within the structure.

I would prefer not to populate all of my "y" fields with NaN for memory management reasons, but I can do this if it is the only work around.

"code" is always fully populated and has no empty cells.  "y" could be fully populated but usually is not.

I am providing a quick example: simplified structure (it is really tens of thousands of entries with 50+ fields)

```
% create example structure
x = struct('y',{1 [] 3 4},'code', {{'a'}, {'b'}, {'c'}, {'b'}});
% concatenate
out = [x.y];
% find indices with code 'b'
ind = find(strcmpi([x.code], 'b'));
% desired output
outSub = out(ind)
```

I would expect *out* to yield:

```
out = [1 NaN 3 4]
```

Instead I get:

```
out = [1 3 4]
```

When trying to use *code* to create an index to find the values in *out* that match the desired code value, this obviously does not work.
Error: **Index exceeds the number of array elements (3).**

The desired output would yield:

```
out = [2 4];
outSub = [NaN 4]
```

I am fully open to indexing in a different way as well.

Comment: You can make `out` a cell array like `out = {x.y}`, if that works for you.

Comment: @beaker - outstanding! I love simple solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Using the comment above, here is the final solution:

```
% create example structure
x = struct('y',{1 [] 3 4},'code', {{'a'}, {'b'}, {'c'}, {'b'}});
% concatenate
out = {x.y};
% find indices with code 'b'
ind = find(strcmpi([x.code], 'b'));
% desired output - cell array
outSubCell = out(ind);
% substitute [] for NaN
outSubCell(cellfun('isempty',outSubCell)) = {NaN};
% convert output to double array
outSub = cell2mat(outSubCell)
```